# Calculation of times off milliseconds to time

Tags: java, time, logic

This code below is used to format milliseconds. The calculations are off by a long shot. I need some help with it. Output of my code is below as well as the milliseconds into a Date class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Wrong Time: " + getTime(999999999 * 599));

}

//Being called into this method is milliseconds = 598999999401
public static String getTime(long miliseconds) {
    int years = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7*52*12)));
    int months = (int) (miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7*52) % 12);
    int weeks = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7)) % 52);
    int days = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24)) % 7);
    int hours = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    int minutes = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int seconds = (int) (miliseconds / 1000) % 60;
    Date date = new Date(598999999401L);//This gets the real time
    System.out.println("Right Time: " + date.getYear() + " years " + (int)(date.getMonth() % 12) + " months " + (int)(date.getDay() % 52) + " weeks "
            + (int)(date.getDay() % 7) + " days " + (int)(date.getHours() % 24) + " hours " + (int)(date.getMinutes() % 60) + " minutes " +
            + (int)(date.getSeconds() % 60) + " seconds");
    return (years <= 0 ? "" : years + " year" + (years != 1 ? "s" : "")) +
            (months <= 0 ? "" : " " + months + " month" + (months != 1 ? "s" : "")) +
            (weeks <= 0 ? "" : " " + weeks + " week" + (weeks != 1 ? "s" : "")) +
            (days <= 0 ? "" : " " + days + " day" + (days != 1 ? "s" : "")) +
            (hours <= 0 ? "" : " " + hours + " hour" + (hours != 1 ? "s" : "")) + 
            (minutes <= 0 ? "" : " " + minutes + " minute" + (minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")) +
            (seconds <= 0 ? "" : " " + seconds + " second" + (seconds != 1 ? "s" : ""));
}
```

Correct Output(Date class)

```
Right Time: 88 years 11 months 6 weeks 6 days 14 hours 53 minutes 19 seconds
```

Wrong Output(My method)

```
Wrong Time:  1 month 3 weeks 2 days 3 hours 25 minutes 45 seconds
```

UPDATE 1 (NEW CALCULATIONS)(Still has logic errors):

```
int years = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7*4*12)));
int months = (int) (miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7*4) % 12);
int weeks = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7)) % 4);
int days = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24)) % 7);
int hours = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
int minutes = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int seconds = (int) (miliseconds / 1000) % 60;
```

Comment: where in this code you calculate `Wrong Time` ?

Comment: getTime(long milliseconds) is being called all of the variables is where it's being calculated.

Comment: Are you aware that date-time libraries exist for this work? In Joda-Time, look at the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html) class and PeriodFormatter class.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues.

Your code seems to reflect a belief that there are 52 weeks in a month.  These are the two lines at fault.

```
int years = (int) ((miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7*52*12)));
int months = (int) (miliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7*52) % 12);
```

Also, you're using `int` where you should be using `long`.  The maximum `int` number of milliseconds is just under 25 days, so you can never do date/time arithmetic with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is int overflow since your main method is using int literals, not longs.  Try:

```
System.out.println("Wrong Time: " + getTime(999999999L * 599L));
```

Also, don't use magic numbers. Use constants that make sense and that make your code self-commenting:

```
private static final int MILI_PER_SEC = 1000;
private static final int SEC_PER_MIN = 60;
private static final int MIN_PER_HR = 60;
private static final int HR_PER_DAY = 24;
private static final int DAYS_PER_YR = 365;
```

and then,

```
int years = (int) (miliseconds / (MILI_PER_SEC * SEC_PER_MIN * MIN_PER_HR * 
                  HR_PER_DAY * DAYS_PER_YR));
```

---

Also, your calculations are all off. You shouldn't be using weeks in the year calculation at all. Use constants, have them make sense. And how do you know that the "correct" result is in fact correct? You are using deprecated code, and Date doesn't use miliseconds the way that you think that it does. It calculates the date relative to January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT as per the [Date API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

Comment: Same effect but the calculations say it's only 2 weeks now. I also changed it directly to 598999999401L